# App I uploaded to Google Play Store now says it's not compatible on my device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, compatibility, google-play-console

I created an App in Unity for Android, testing on Samsung Galaxy A50 and Samsung Tab S5e and it all worked perfectly fine.
Now I've uploaded it to the Google Play Store, I can't download it, it says 'You device isn't compatible with this version'.

The Android version is set to 8.0 and above in Unity and the devices I used to test on are above that (9 and 10)

Here is the App info on Google Play Store:

```html
Features (11)
android.hardware.camera, android.hardware.camera.ar, android.hardware.camera.autofocus, android.hardware.camera.front, android.hardware.location, android.hardware.location.gps, android.hardware.touchscreen, android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch, android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct, android.hardware.wifi, com.google.ar.core.depth

Screen layouts (4)
small, normal, large, xlarge

Required permissions (11)
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE

Localisations (146)
af, am, ar, ar_EG, ar_SA, az, az_AZ, be, be_BY, bg, bn, bn_BD, bs, bs_BA, ca, cs, da, de, de_AT, de_CH, el, en_AU, en_CA, en_GB, en_IE, en_IN, en_SG, en_XC, en_ZA, es, es_419, es_AR, es_BO, es_CL, es_CO, es_CR, es_DO, es_EC, es_GT, es_HN, es_MX, es_NI, es_PA, es_PE, es_PR, es_PY, es_SV, es_US, es_UY, es_VE, et, et_EE, eu, eu_ES, fa, fi, fil, fr, fr_CA, fr_CH, gl, gl_ES, gsw, gu, gu_IN, he, hi, hr, hu, hy, hy_AM, id, in, is, is_IS, it, iw, ja, ka, ka_GE, kk, kk_KZ, km, km_KH, kn, kn_IN, ko, ky, ky_KG, lo, lo_LA, lt, lv, mk, mk_MK, ml, ml_IN, mn, mn_MN, mo, mr_IN, ms, ms_MY, my, my_MM, nb, ne, ne_NP, nl, no, pa, pa_IN, pl, pt, pt_BR, pt_PT, ro, ru, si, si_LK, sk, sl, sq, sq_AL, sr, sr_Latn, sv, sw, ta, ta_IN, te, te_IN, th, tl, tr, uk, ur, ur_PK, uz, uz_UZ, vi, zh, zh_CN, zh_HK, zh_TW, zu

Native platforms (2)
arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
```

here is my Android Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.product">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />"/>

  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
  
  
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="net.sanukin.OverrideUnityActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required"  tools:replace="android:value"/>
   <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I can't work out what the issue is. Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I've worked out what was wrong. This may not be the solution to everyone who has this problem but hopefully it will help someone out.

The issue was with ARCore. In the XR Plug-in Management settings, I changed Depth the 'Optional'. With it previously set to 'Required' it was excluding all the devices that weren't capable of it yet.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the internet:
"To fix the “your device is not compatible with this version” error message, try clearing the Google Play Store cache, and then data. Next, restart the Google Play Store and try installing the app again." (from [https://support.getupside.com/hc/en-us/articles/226667067--Device-not-compatible-error-message-in-Google-Play-Store#:~:text=It%20appears%20to%20be%20an,try%20installing%20the%20app%20again.&text=From%20here%20navigate%20to%20Apps%2C%20or%20App%20Manager.](https://support.getupside.com/hc/en-us/articles/226667067--Device-not-compatible-error-message-in-Google-Play-Store#:%7E:text=It%20appears%20to%20be%20an,try%20installing%20the%20app%20again.&text=From%20here%20navigate%20to%20Apps%2C%20or%20App%20Manager.))
Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this but had no luck. I think the issue is with the APK I'm uploading to Google Play Console. The devices that I was testing on are not showing up in the device catalogue, suggesting that there's something in my Unity project that is preventing compatibility